# Specify output attributes for generated JSON for polymorphic associations

Tags: javalite, activeweb

I linked 2 tables to its common one using polymorphic association:

```
@BelongsToPolymorphic(parents = {Application.class, SiteSection.class})
public class Parameter extends Model {
    static {
        validatePresenceOf("parent_id", "parent_type");
    }
}
```

The query used in the controller is like that:

```
String siteSettingsParameters = SiteSection.where("site_id=?", site.getId()).include(Parameter.class).toJson(false);
```

The result JSON contains children node:

```
[
    {
        "id": 253,
        "section_id": 60,
        "site_id": 61,
        "children": {
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2017-12-19T15:50:28Z",
                    "id": 145,
                    "parent_id": 253,
                    "parent_type": "app.models.SiteSection",
                    "updated_at": "2017-12-19T15:50:28Z",
                    "value": "Terrible Swift Sword"
                }
            ]
        }
    },  
    {
        "id": 254,
        "section_id": 61,
        "site_id": 61,
        "children": {
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2017-12-19T15:50:28Z",
                    "id": 146,
                    "parent_id": 254,
                    "parent_type": "app.models.SiteSection",
                    "updated_at": "2017-12-19T15:50:28Z",
                    "value": "Sleep the Brave"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
...]
```

Is it possible to **skip** the children node in a Java class to map to the above JSON ?

Here is the content of the java class I'd like to map the JSON (I omitted the accessors methods):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SiteSectionDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private SectionDTO section;
    private SiteDTO site;

    @JsonProperty("children")
    private List<ParameterDTO> parameters;
...
accessors come here
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Write getter methods on your models, and use Jackson to generate JSON rather than rely on a built-in mechanizm.
2. Use ActiveWeb views and partials to generate your JSON.

I personally opt for the second approach since it is already built into the framework, and is the most flexible and readable.

Let's say you need to return people and their addresses. 
Here is your `PeopleController#index()` method:

```
public void index(){
   view("people", Person.findAll().include(Address.class).orderBy("id"));
   render().contentType("application/json");
}
```

As you can see, we use an `include()` method to pre-cache addresses.

The `index.ftl` view looks like this:

```
[<@render partial="person" collection=people spacer="comma"/>]
```

Now, pay attention here.The first and last characters are `[` and `]`, which are brackets identifying an array in JSON. 
The content is a partial called `person`. This will be automatically invoked for every value in a collection 'people', and their contents will be interleaved by a content from a partial `comma`.

Lets see the contents of a partial `person`:

```
{
   "id" : ${person.id},
   "first_name" : "${person.first_name}",
   "last_name" : "${person.last_name}",
   "addresses" : [<@render partial="address" collection=person.getAddresses() spacer="comma"/> ]
}
```

ActiveWeb automatically has an object available named by the name of the partial itself, in this case `person`.

Here you can make choices as far as what property to display and in what order. The `addresses` collection uses the same technique, and just calls the `address` partial with a collection `person.getAddresses()`. 
The contents of a `comma` partial is a single character: `,`.

You can examine/run example app REST service build in JavaLite/ActiveWeb: 
https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-rest/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/people

If you run this sample app and follow the steps in the README file, you will see this JSON in your output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Marylin",
    "last_name": "Monroe",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "address_type": "residential",
        "address1": "123 Pine St",
        "address2": "Apt 3",
        "city": "Chicago",
        "state": "IL",
        "zip": "60606"
      },
      {
        "address_type": "shipping",
        "address1": "135 S LaSalle St",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "Chicago",
        "state": "IL",
        "zip": "60604"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Kennedy",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "address_type": "residential",
        "address1": "456 Pine St",
        "address2": "Apt 5",
        "city": "Chicago",
        "state": "IL",
        "zip": "60606"
      },
      {
        "address_type": "shipping",
        "address1": "200 N LaSalle St",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "Chicago",
        "state": "IL",
        "zip": "60604"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Really cool, Igor ! Thanks a lot for such e detailed explanation ! I couldn't even imagine to use views and partials to render the JSON I need. Just great !

Comment: enjoy! JavaLite is a mature system, if you have a problem, chances  are it has a solution

Comment: Thank you ! The last one: is there a way to have foreign keys IDs as Integer and not as Strings in generated JSON ? I have `id` correct as Integer but it is not the case for foreign keys which are as follows: `id": 253,
"section_id": "60"`. I'm using `Postgresql 9.6.10`.

Comment: It is just FreeMarker at this point, use `"id": ${id}` instead of `"id" : "${id}"`